# getting hash link in same page regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex, hash

I want to get the hash link which is targeted to as section in the same page.
Suppose i have a link `<a href="#todo">to do</a>` and i have a section having id `todo` :  . Now first i want to detect if it is a link with hash and then grab the target and scrollTo the target.

### My js is

```
var urlPatt = /#\S+/g;
    $(document).on('click', '.nav-menu li a', function (e) {
        if (urlPatt.match($(this).attr('href'))){
           console.log($(this).attr('href'))
        }
    });
```

But it is not consoling any thing

Answer (score 0):

```
string.match(regexp)
regexp.exec(string)
regexp.test(string)
```

all exist. `regexp.match(string)` is not a thing.